# Why 401 unauthorized happen, although CORS is used?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API for Windows authentication which is like this:

```
[HttpGet("GetIdentity")]
public IActionResult GetIdentity()
{
    var userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    return Ok(new { UserName = userName });
}
```

and everything works fine. Then I called this API from reactjs like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function UserNameApi() {
  const [users, setUser] = useState("");

  const fetchData = () => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8000/User/GetIdentity",{withCredentials:true})
    .then((res) => {res.json()
    .then((result) => setUser(result.userName));
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>UserName:{users}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default UserNameApi;
```

I published both server and client side on IIS but as I open the page, I get an http 401 unauthorized error. I can call the API in the browser, and also used postman and by setting NTLM it works too. I also have set CORS in API and IIS.

I will appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After adding below code and facing CORS issue.

Change AddCors code like below can fix it.

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        }));
        ...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
...
```

---

In addition to setting "withCredentials" to "true", you should also set "credentials" to "include". This should allow the browser to send the Windows credentials to the server.

**Code should like below:**

```
const fetchData = () => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8000/User/GetIdentity",{
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: "include"
    })
    .then((res) => {
      res.json()
      .then((result) => setUser(result.userName));
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it didn't solve. here is the error: /about:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/User/GetIdentity' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
UserNameApi.js:8          GET http://localhost:8000/User/GetIdentity net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

Comment: This another issue, please check the project which using 8000 port and enable cors in that project, then you can fix the issue.

Comment: I have dine that: builder.Services.AddCors((opt) => opt.AddPolicy("Default", (p) =>
{
    p.AllowAnyHeader();
    p.AllowAnyOrigin();
    p.AllowAnyMethod();
}));

Comment: @SoudabehParsa [How to enable cors in blazor server backend application ?](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-you-enable-cors-in-a-blazor-server-application)

Comment: @SoudabehParsa could you share your program.cs file, we need to check the order of the middleware.

Comment: I send it as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251681/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-soudabeh-parsa).

Comment: this answer helped me. but also there must be some changes in program.cs too. this part should be added to AddCors======> .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)