# Asp.net core with windows authentication gets CORS error for post request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors

I have changed the VS settings to work with Window Authentication:
[image]

and changed the launchSetting.json file:

```
{

  "iisSettings": {

    "windowsAuthentication": true,

    "anonymousAuthentication": false,

    "iisExpress": {

      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40825",

      "sslPort": 44361

    }
```

Everything works as expected for **GET** requests. For **Post** requests, the following CORS error comes up:
[image]

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

        {

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            //    var emailconfig = Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>();

            //    services.AddSingleton(emailconfig);

 

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            

             services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(

                builder =>

                {

                   // builder.AllowAnyOrigin();

                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();

                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();

                    builder.AllowCredentials();

                    //builder.SetPreflightMaxAge(new System.TimeSpan(0));

                })

            //options => options.WithOrigins(clientUrl).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST")

            //options => options.WithOrigins(clientUrl).AllowAnyHeader().WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST").AllowCredentials().SetPreflightMaxAge(new System.TimeSpan(1728000))

 

            );

 

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();

            services.AddTransient<INegotiationService, NegotiationService>();

            services.AddTransient<INegotiationLinesService, NegotiationLinesService>();

            services.AddTransient<IRFQLinesService, RFQLinesService>();

            services.AddTransient<INotificationQueueService, NotificationQueueService>();

 

            

 

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

            DAL.DBAccess.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("VPADB");

            DAL.VPAServiceAccess.WS_VPA_Endpoint_URL = Configuration.GetConnectionString("HPOLoadWS");

 

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>

            {

                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "VPARestfulService", Version = "v1" });

            });

 

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(o => {

                o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;

                o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;

                o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;

            });

 

         

 

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>

            {

                options.AddPolicy("AllUsers", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());

            });

            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

 

        }

 

 

 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

        {

 

 

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                app.UseSwagger();

                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "VPARestfulService v1"));

 

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

 

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()

            {

                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"StaticFiles")),

                RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")

            });

 

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();

 

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

 

 

 

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>

            {

                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapHub<notificationHub>("/notification");

            });

        }
```

**The controller:**

```
  [ApiController]

    [Route("api/[controller]")]

    [Authorize]

    public class VPAController : Controller
```

**web config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

       <system.web>

                <authentication mode="Windows" />

                     <authorization>

                       <allow verbs="OPTIONS" users="*"/>

                       <deny users="?" />

                </authorization>

 

       </system.web>

 

       <appSettings>

              <!--The license context used-->

              <add key="EPPlus:ExcelPackage.LicenseContext" value="NonCommercial" />

       </appSettings>

       <system.webServer>

              <handlers>

                     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />

              </handlers>

              <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\VPARestfulService.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />

              <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

                     <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>

                     <!-- ADD THIS -->   

              </modules>

              <security>

                     <requestFiltering>

                           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />

                     </requestFiltering>

              </security>

              <httpProtocol>

                     <customHeaders>

                           <!-- <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> -->

                           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD" />

                           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>

                     </customHeaders>

              </httpProtocol>

 

       </system.webServer>

</
```

**In the front end**
I am using angular and set *withCredentials:true* :

```
return this.http.post(`${this.url}/ResolveSnOPLoad?snopid=${proc.snOP.id}`, {},{  withCredentials: true })

                .pipe(

                    map(resp => {

                        let snop = <VPASnOPModel>resp;

                        this.setSnOPInProc(proc, snop, false);

 

                        return snop;

                    })

                );
```

Unfortunately, it is not helping as the CORS error persists for all the post requests.

I tried to change the CORS configurations in the Startup.cs file
also added attributes in the controller
and added **withcredntials:true** in the front end. I am still getting the CORS error from the backend.

Comment: [Does the answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75369693/7687666)