# CORS issue in React, TS, Vite App and My backEnd .net

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, vite

I am trying to post a Request using Fetch and Axios, and having a CORS issue in my application on the IIS Server.

My Server API settings are :

> ```
> <httpProtocol>
>   <customHeaders>
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
>   </customHeaders>
> </httpProtocol>
> ```

I have created a function for POST Request:

```
async function httpPostRequest<T = any>(url: string, data: object): Promise<T> {
      try {
          const response = await fetch(url, {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Assuming JSON data is being sent
                  // Add any other headers as needed
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(data), // Convert data to JSON string
          });
          if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
          }
    
          return await response.json(); // Parse response body as JSON
      } catch (error) {
          throw error;
      }
    }
    
    export default httpPostRequest;
```

Below is the method How I am calling the above method for call the API :

```
const getRowdata = () => {
    httpPostRequest(`${API_BASE_URL}Screener/GetScreenerDataNew`, {
        dropDownType: selected.type,
        id: selected.value,
        tabValue: tab.head,
        subTabValue: tab.currentSubTab
    }).then((resData) => {
        setRowData(resData);

        if (tab.head === "Overview") {
            const extractedIds: string[] = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < resData.length; i++) {
                const stockCompanyId: string = resData[i].stock_company_id.toString(); 
                extractedIds.push(stockCompanyId);
            }
            setStockIds(extractedIds);
        }

        getDate(resData[0].date_);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know ASP.NET CORE is corss-platform. In IIS, we can set the CORS settings like yours (Machine Level). But we usually recommend setting up CORS at the application level. Like below:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        }));
        ...

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

For more details, please [check my sample code here in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75369693/7687666).

If you are using windows authentication, we have to set the CORS in machine level, and use `withCredentials` when we use `fetch` method.

Comment: I Have resolved this issue after making some fixed in web.config